# Why PHPMailer is not sending message to gmx.de mail service provider?

Tags: php, email

I have an email here: **gmx.de**

When I send an email from my **Gmail account** to **gmx.de account** then it's working fine :)

But when I try to send email using PHPMailer to my **gmx.de account** then I don't receive any message in my **gmx.de account** but in PHP it's showing success message.

PHP code:

```
<?php
include('phpmailer/PHPMailer.php');

$email            = new PHPMailer();        
$email->isHTML(true);
$email->From      = 'xxx@gmail.com';
$email->FromName  = 'Test Name';
$email->Subject   = 'Test Subject';
$email->Body      = 'This is a test message';
$email->AddAddress('xxx.xxx@gmx.de');   

if ( $email->Send() ) {
    echo 'mail sent';
} else {
    echo 'sorry not sendt';
}
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: could you cach any errors or exceptions?

Comment: @SuYang I can't see any error message.\

Comment: Do you have a 2 factor autentication for the gmail account? 
Check it, because it cause problems when you try to send email like this.

Comment: @DiabloSteve from my gmail account the mail is sending. But using PHPMailer() it's not sending message to my gmx.de account.

Comment: Have you even configure PHPMailer? Have you added SMTP service which should be used? Gmail in your case. You then also need to allow 3rd part programms in GMail account

Comment: @Xplatforms but the PHPMailer is sending email properly to gmail and yahoo account !

Comment: I know, but you need SMTP connection in PHP which connect to the Gmail, and then you can send. You find answer down.

Comment: @DiabloSteve Okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to connect to an SMTP server first, like the Gmail SMTP and than you can send email. Take care for the 2 factor authentication, because a simple connection will be not enought.
You can find some code here:
[Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Comment: It's ONLY not sending email to gmx.de account but other like gmail and yahoo is fine !

Comment: Do you have SMTP server? You need to configure the PHP server to connect to an SMTP server which will send your email. There is an example for connection to the Gmail SMTP. You can use other SMTP server, but you need one, which sending your email.

Comment: Okay. I am trying to do this

Comment: Cool. Good luck. I just wrote the Gmail, it's just an example, but you can config other SMTP for it. It's up to you.

Comment: Thank You Man :)